# Array localstorage doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a problem: I can't fix a bug on my function.
The `for` run just 2 times. Not 4.

Any one can help?

I tried many types of `for` and `while`, change localstorage types but nothing changed.

```
    function saveEdits() {

    for ( i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
          alert(i);
            localStorage[i] = document.getElementById("tmp"+i).innerHTML
            alert("tmp"+i);
      }
 }
    function trocaimage(){

    document.getElementById("fundo").src = "/data/"+document.getElementById("txtfoto").text;
    }
function checkEdits() {
document.getElementById("tmp1").innerHTML = localStorage[1];
document.getElementById("tmp2").innerHTML = localStorage[2];
document.getElementById("tmp3").innerHTML = localStorage[3];
document.getElementById("tmp4").innerHTML = localStorage[4];
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console? Perhaps there is no `#tmp3`?

Comment: [**Your code works**](http://jsfiddle.net/vp8v5fq1/). Unless you do not have a `#tmp3`, `#tmp4` & `#tmp5` in your HTML? It runs **5** times, as expected (not 4, because `i` iterates from `1` to `5`).

Comment: i need just until tmp4. all tmps until tmp4 are create and working... just dont know why when i depurate stop to work on tmp3 =/  whana see more of my page?